# count(*) on Avro table returns 0

Tags: hive, avro

I've recently moved to using `AvroSerDe` for my External tables in Hive.

```
Select col_name,count(*)
from table
group by col_name;
```

The above query gives me a count. Where as the below query does not:

```
Select count(*)
from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is hive just looks at the table metadata and fetches the values. For some reason, statistics for the table is not updated in hive due to which count(*) returns 0.

The statistics is written with no data rows at the time of table creation and for any data appends/changes, hive requires to update this statistics in the metadata.

Running ANALYZE command gather statistics and write them into Hive MetaStore.

`ANALYZE TABLE table_name COMPUTE STATISTICS;`

Visit [Apache Hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev) for more details about ANALYZE command.

**Other methods to solve this issue**

- Use of 'limit' and 'group by' clause triggers map reduce job to get
  the count of number of rows and gives correct value
- Setting fetch task conversion to none forces hive to run a map reduce
  job to count the number of rows

  `hive> set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none;`